# I want to run magic command % somefile.py inside a jupyter notebook. However, this program requires variables from the main script

Tags: jupyter-notebook, magic-command

To clarify, somfile.py needs variables that are generated from main.ipynb. So, when I simply do %run somefile.py I get this error:

NameError: name 'viewer' is not defined

This viewer is defined in the main code above. However, now if I use %load somefile.py and THEN run it, it works fine. But, the whole point of me doing this is to not show the users of my script, the nitty gritty details. I am preparing this for some students.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation of the magic command %run](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run) covers use of the `-i` option to "run the file in IPython’s namespace instead of an empty one." You want to add that flag to your `%run` command:

```bash
viewer = "something"
%run -i my_script.py
```

It applies to notebook kernel namespace as IPython was incorporated into the IPython notebook, which became the Jupyter notebook project later.

Comment: Wow cant believe how simple it was. Thanks a lot Wayne